# creating custom itemrenderer for datagrid using actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have overriden the function found in DataGrid Class

> [Bindable]
>
> protected var dgir:DefaultGridItemRenderer = new DefaultGridItemRenderer();
>
> override public function set itemRenderer (value:IFactory) : void {
> dgir.label = "Sample Text";
>
> }

I'm still having errors running it.

Answer (score 0):

> http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/AS3-flex-Sort-DataGrid-DataGridColumn-which-contains-custom-ItemRenderer

May this link'll be helpfull!